# How to select row in FastObjectListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I really lost heart in tries how to select row in the FastObjectListView (C#, Windows Forms).

I have object and index of this object in the grid, but i can't make it selected!
All i've made - move scroll to this row, but not select it.

Methods:

```
idx = index of row with my object
obj = my object

gvRaces.Items[idx].Selected = true;
gvRaces.SelectObject(obj , true);
gvRaces.SelectedItem = (OLVListItem)gvRaces.Items.Find(obj.Id.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault(); -
```

*for last method i have a question. What is a key in method ...Items.Find(key, searchAllSubitems)?*

all of this methods change properties in my fastObjectListView, but don't change any items visually.

How to select my row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the right answer:

```
gvRaces.SelectObject(obj , true);
```

This would also work (and is probably more what you want):

```
gvRaces.SelectedObject = obj;
```

Rev1.0's point is still valid -- make sure that `obj` is actually an object in the control. The control uses `Equals()` to decide if two objects are equal.

Also, ensure that `olv.HideSelection` is `false`. This is a very annoying MS provided property that turns off selection when the `ListView` doesn't have focus. It makes it look as if `SelectObject()` hasn't worked when it actually has.

Comment: absolutely right! HideSelection was a source of all problem!

Answer (score 0):

In short: You are doing it wrong. When working with ObjectListView or any of the related controls you never touch the Items collection or ListViewItems in general directly.

You should read the tutorial, especially [Mental gear shift](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/gettingStarted.html#mental-gear-shift) and [Unlearn you must](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/gettingStarted.html#unlearn-you-must).

> Beware of ListViewItems. You never need to add ListViewItems to an ObjectListView. **If you find yourself adding things to the Items collection, creating ListViewItems, or adding sub-items to anything, then you need to stop** – you are being seduced to the dark side. An ObjectListView does all that work for you. It owns the ListViewItems and will destroy and recreate them as needed. Your job is to tell the ObjectListView what information you want the ListViewItems to contain, and then to give it the list of objects to show.
>
> **Resist the temptation to add, edit, remove, or otherwise mess with ListViewItems – it will not work.**

Comment: How to do it correctly? I don't change my collection, i just want to imitate user click on item of the list!

Comment: I did not notice your "gvRaces.SelectObject(obj , true);" before. That would probably be the correct way, but you have to make sure that "obj" really is the same object (the same reference) as the one you want to select in the OLV. A common mistake is to fill the OLV from a database query and later want to select one of those objects specifying an object from a second query.